# How to implement paypal recurring payment with using IPN in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hii I am using paypal recurring payment in **codeigniter**. But i want to use IPN inside this. Here is my form in a view file.

```
$paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$merchant_email = 'futureloop@merchent.com';    

<form name="_xclick" action="<?php echo $paypal_url;?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $merchant_email; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">    
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="54.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">       
</form>
```

How can i use IPN inside this in codeigniter?

**Please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

checkout below documentation link where you can setup for IPN and also you will get same code for PHP regarding how to listen IPN data and how process it.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

**For listening paypal IPN**

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php